# User input not showing in search form

Tags: php, html, css

I have a free form search that I moved from my main content to my header.  Once I moved the form into the header the text inside of it stopped showing.  The placeholder works but when you begin typing it is completely blank.  The search and the functionality work perfectly, I just cannot see what I am typing.  Any ideas?

```
<form class="search" action="/all-results/" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <span class="text"><input name="searchProducts" value="All" type="hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="search_selection" value="all">
        <input name="byString" id="s" type="text"  value="" placeholder="<?php echo __('Search','Avada'); ?>" /></span>
    </fieldset>

    <form  name="input" action="/all-results/" method="get"> 
        <input type="submit" id="search_button" value="Search">
    </form>
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue.. Try inspecting the element?  My guess is the font color is being changed and it is matching the background color.

Comment: Why the nested forms with the same action to? Why not just use an `isset`?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. You can **not** nest a `<form>` element inside another `<form>`. Messing up forms and tables are two of the best ways to produces peculiar browser behaviour, so my guess is that this is your problem.

If you correct your HTML ([validate it](http://validator.w3.org/)!) and the problem persists, then post a **minimal** HTML page **with** CSS so that there is something for us to debug.